# How do I make an HTTPS POST request in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, https

I'm fairly new to Swift. I am trying to make an HTTPS POST to https url with a specific header. Note HTTPS not HTTP. How do I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant't figure out how to do it for httpS (note the S). @inorganik

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's http or https, the process is the same

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/2011447-setvalue).

For example, to set the `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = "id=42".data(using: .utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    // ...
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Will this work with an HTTPS url?

Comment: Yes, it will. In fact, it's easier because you don't have to do anything silly with the "App Transport Security Settings" in the Info.plist with https.